# What program do I use to open the .iso file I download to use for installing ubuntu?

Tags: iso

I was able to get Unetbootin and be able to download ubuntu on a usb stick and use the live version.  I'm still trying to figure out why Wubi will not work.  When I try to download the .iso, Firefox asks me which program to use to open it with.  I'm not sure what to do from there.

Comment: I just plugged in my usb stick and clicked on Wubi to run Ubuntu and the numerous cancel try again and continue window popped up.  After I clicked it several times (I stopped counting after about 20) it brought me to the Wubi menu Install window with the options to use the demo, install inside Windows, or Learn More.  I'm happy it is working but the pop up screens are still bugging me.

Comment: I burn the ISO to a CD with InfraRecorder. But you can also open the ISO with 7-Zip.

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing at first.

When you download the .iso with firefox, you would save the file rather then opening it.

If you do not have any CD burning software installed, windows does not know what to do with an .iso, it thinks it is an archive (zip) file.

You do NOT extract or unzip the iso.

You have several options at this point

1. Install ubuntu with the wubi installer

follow the instructions on this page :

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

1. You can also use unetbootin to "install" the ubuntu iso to a flash drive. You would then re boot your computer and during the boot process boot from the flash drive.
2. Burn the ubuntu .iso to a CD

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

You can then either re-boot or run the wubi installer

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9142/easily-install-ubuntu-linux-with-windows-using-the-wubi-installer/

==== STOP ====

1. You sound very new to Ubuntu and before you do much else I highly suggest you back up any data you do not want to loose. Although data loss is rare it can happen if you click the wrong button when installing Ubuntu.
2. Understand the difference between installing Ubuntu in the standard method, ie partitioning your hard drive, and wubi.

I already gave you a link for wubi, here is a link for a standard install

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall

1. Understand how Linux identifies partitions. Windows uses letters, such as C:\

Linux uses /dev/sda

See : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=282018

I know it may seem overwhelming at first, but understanding those few items will help prevent a mistake and potential data loss.

good luck to you.

Comment: is this your "final answer"

Answer (score 0):

*(OP solved issue)*

I just plugged in my usb stick and clicked on Wubi to run Ubuntu and the numerous cancel try again and continue window popped up. After I clicked it several times (I stopped counting after about 20) it brought me to the Wubi menu Install window with the options to use the demo, install inside Windows, or Learn More. I'm happy it is working but the pop up screens are still bugging me. – keith Dec 4 '11 at 3:29

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use 'Open with...'**, use **'Save (as)'** instead. Right click and set the default application as **Windows Disk Image Burner**. Boot from the Live CD and when prompted, select **custom installation**, then partition your USB and install it on it just like you would with your hard drive.